# Android Location Not Available when there is no GPS

Tags: android, gps, location, android-manifest, locationmanager

I would like location information to be available to my App, from GPS if available, and if not from other means such as Wifi.

Location info works fine with GPS, but if I turn 
Settings->Personal->Location Mode = Battery Saving
to exercise a non GPS scenario, or just run the App where these is no access to GPS, location information is no longer available to the App.

In my code this test returns false when GPS is not available :

```
        string Provider = LocationManager.GpsProvider;
        if (m_LocMgr.IsProviderEnabled(Provider))
            Log.Info("location available");
        else
            Log.Info("location NOT available");
```

My manifest.xml is set up as follows :

```
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
...
```

Any ideas please.  How can I enable location services when GPS is not available

Comment: What about the network provider of `LocationManager` ?

Comment: Thanks Blackkara. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply to enable the Network provider in addition the GPS one.

```
        Provider = LocationManager.NetworkProvider;
        if (m_LocMgr.IsProviderEnabled(Provider))
            m_LocMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(Provider, 2000, 1, this);
```

I had misread the permissions documentation. Just because it says that if you use Fine (GPS) permissions you implicitly get Coarse (Network) permissions, does NOT mean that you dont need to enable them both in code.